# Reactjs life cycle: call while only change state

Tags: reactjs

In below image we have react life cycle methods. 
Is there any other method which will call only when we change the state only ?

Here shouldComponentUpdate & comonentWillUpdate both will call in case of changes into props and state.

Thank you in Advance !!!

[image]

Comment: I don't think there's such hook present. Why would you need that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No lifecycle methods exist, but you can use the existing `shouldComponentUpdate` and `componentWillUpdate` hooks and wrap your state change logic in a check to make sure that `previousState !== this.state`

Answer (score 0):

When you change your state, `shouldComponentUpdate` will be called, if this method `return false`. No other lifecyle methods will be called anymore.
So just check and `return false` in `shouldComponentUpdate` if you don't want other lifecycle methods to be called.